# Cognos - Size of the axes in a graph

Tags: graph, cognos

Do you know how it is possible, in a graph, to adjust the size of the Y-axis to correspond to the data?

Screenshot for example : http://hpics.li/296c96c

Thanks for your help ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your response.

It helps me to find how to adapt the Y-axis to the data, in my case where I use a repeater.
we have to uncheck the option "same range for all instances of the graph".

See the screenshot:
http://hpics.li/fb34043

See you :-)

Answer (score 1):

- Click on the Y-axis line (not the 0-n)
- Properties -> Axis Range

[Relevant blog post with pictures](http://therealtoddnappi.blogspot.com/2012/12/cognos-10-axis-range.html)